# requiring a a fixed horizontal line on a times series plot

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

i have a plotly plot based on a time series but now im required to add a fixed horizontal like at y=238 to it 
can you please give me some ideas?

```
fig= plot_ly(
  data = x,
  x = x$time,
  y = x$infected,
  mode = 'lines'
)

fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out with the last line of this

```
fig <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~netA$time, y = ~netA$infected, name = "Infection A", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
  add_lines(x = ~netB$time, y = ~netB$infected, name = "Infection B", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
    add_segments(x = 0, xend = nrow(netA), y = vcount(g_primschool_a), yend = vcount(g_primschool_a))
fig
```

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
fig
abline(h=238, col='red', lw=2)
```

Comment: thanks but abline doesnt work on plotly